# How do I use the custom plugin in <script setup> in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
//TestPlugin.js

const randomValue = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  console.log(random);
};

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.config.globalProperties.$randomValue = randomValue;
  },
};
```

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <button>event</button>
</template>
```

This code is an example. I want to call the randomValue function within `<script setup>` and put it in a button instead of `<buton@click="$randomValue(0, 20)">`

The following is an example of what I want to do.

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <button @click="random">event</button>
</template>
<script setup>
  const random = $randomValue(0,10);
</script>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself...

```
//TestPlugin.js
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.config.globalProperties.$randomValue = randomValue;
    Vue.config.globalProperties.$valueCheck = valueCheck;

    Vue.provide("plugins", { valueCheck, randomValue });
  },
};
```

```
//App.vue
<script setup>
  import { inject } from 'vue';
  const { valueCheck, randomValue } = inject("plugins");
  const hello = () => {
    randomValue(0,10);
  }
</script>
```

I added `Vue.provide("plugins", { valueCheck, randomValue });` and `import { inject } from 'vue'; const { valueCheck, randomValue } = inject("plugins");`